# Unity 2d - Destroying foreign object from script + seek explanation about destroying objects

Tags: c#, unity, 2d, gameobject

I have simple emmiter which sending enemies toward player in center of screen. Player can shoot missile (also emmiter). I want to destroy enemy AND missile in same time.

Here is my code attached to Enemy

```
 public GameObject player;
 public GameObject missile;

 void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
 {
     if (collider.gameObject.name == player.name)
     {
         Destroy(gameObject);
         Application.LoadLevel("Retry");
     }

     if (collider.gameObject.tag == missile.tag)
     {
         Destroy(gameObject);
         Destroy(missile.gameObject);
         Score.killed++;
     }
 }
```

But after missile hit enemy, error in unity occur

> Destroying assets is not permitted to avoid data loss.

Well... im programmer but new in unity. So my question is not that simple : i think im destroying object which is still in use. Am i right? How can i destroy both objects? When i can destroy GameObject? I tried to use this

```
GameObject mssle = Istantiate(missile,missile.transform.position,Quaternion.identity);
Destroy(mssle);
```

as was suggested by good people on unityanswers. Didnt work, missile is stil alive and my answer got rejected. Am i destroying whole prefab or what? This is little confusing for me

Comment: Sounds to me like you're trying to destroy an object in the scene( while not playing the game ) or a prefab.

Comment: well i think im doing something wrong. But really i dont know what and cant get suitable answer or even discussion from unityanswers. Only rejection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you assign a Prefab to `public GameObject missile` in the inspector. When you try to destroy `missile` inside of your `OnTriggerEnter2D` method, the error message does make sense, since you're trying to destroy a prefab and not an instance.

Instead of trying to destroy `missile`, you should destroy the object that collided with your GameObject.

So, replace: `Destroy(missile.gameObject);` with: `Destroy(collider.gameObject);` (you can be sure to destroy a collided missile here, since you already checked the matching tag in your if statement: `if (collider.gameObject.tag == missile.tag)`)

Comment: this is actually working! And you gave me excelent explanation why it was happening, i understand what was wron! Thanks much and i must say: blame unity community. Dont have rep here to upvote :(